# Constant object allocation in Memory Profiler

Tags: android, memory, android-profiler

My app is always allocating objects while running. When it runs idle, the colored memory graphs in Memory Profiler are staying flat. But the white dashed line of allocated objects is constantly growing. It starts at 110K, reaching 250K and more. GC is dropping it back to 110K sometimes, but then it continues to grow again. Is it a normal behavior? If not, what to do with that?

Comment: Do you have animations playing in the loop on that screen? Profiler allows you to check what kind of objects are being allocated. I will suggest you to check that.

Comment: no animations, UI is completely idle. there's a listener that polls card reader every second

Comment: It's pretty normal. Even if your card reader routine uses only simple objects like `Char` and `Integer`, those still have to be allocated on the heap, and eventually GC'd, once they pile up high enough.